# Comparing Large CSV file rows to other rows - Python - Memory Issues

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, memory

I'm relatively naive when it comes to Python so apologies for any irrelevant statements.

I have a CSV file with approx 500k rows that I'm working with. (~60 MB)

I need to do some basic cleaning of the file as I read it in, which is fine, but I also need to compare each row of the CSV to every other row of the same file. Originally I had loaded the file and stored it in a List and then looped over it twice to compare rows. This is probably a dumb way to do this as I ran out of memory extremely quickly. It looked something like this:

```
for row in self.trainingdata:
        for row2 in self.trainingdata:
            # Do Stuff
```

My question is, what is the most memory efficient way to do this? Should I open the same file twice and compare each row as it comes in? Or is there a better way to store the data? I'm looking for some high level guidance on what the best approach is. My current idea is something like below but I haven't completed it yet:

```
with open('/ThisIsTheFile', 'rU') as csvread:
        reader = csv.reader(csvread, delimiter=',')
        with open('/ThisIsTheFile', 'rU') as csvread2:
            reader2 = csv.reader(csvread2, delimiter=',')
            #Do Stuff
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That is not a very large file, where are you running this from?

Comment: Take a look at filecmp. Have this be a precursor to your method. So it'll run through identical ones quickly instead of looping

Comment: what kind of comparison are you doing? is 1 row against every row in the file? is one row against one other specific row in the file? have you tried the **deepcopy** module? i could help with not having to read the file again

Comment: @GermanRosales, how will deepcopy help? reading the file would not be causing a  memory issue, storing even more data would

Comment: _Should I open the same file twice_ No **deepcopy** will help with getting a copy of the list

Comment: @GermanRosales, copy of what list?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Let me clarify. I am comparing each row to each other row in the file to attempt to find duplicates. However, I have to do quite a few permutations/calculations on each of the columns when im comparing them to each other so its not as easy as simply checking for ==. I end up with a boolean for each combination of 2 rows, that holds whether or not they are duplicates. I am able to read the csv file and save it into a list without issue. I ran into issue when I created two instances of the list and used the nested loop for comparison (500k rows x 500k rows).

Comment: Also, @GermanRosales thanks for the suggestions on deepcopy - I was not familiar with this so I will definitely take a look.

Comment: 60MB isn't that bad as 500K strings on most PCs.  You don't actually need deepcopy, or to open the file twice.  One thing you might consider is if you can figure out a key that describes a line in such a way that two equivalent lines would have the same key.  Then you could easily use defaultdict to maintain a list of lines (or even line numbers) that match a key.

Comment: @BrandonWind I was thinking this carefully and Why not creating a dictionary where the key is an ident value for each line and asking if the value already exist before adding a new elements?, That would give you the duplicates without having to compare 2 lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Padraic pointed out, this file is not large enough to worry about running out of memory. About an optimal way to do what you want is to use a dictionary like in this code sample:

```
dictio = {}
file2 = open(file)
for line in file2.readlines():
    parts = line.split(' ')
    if parts[0] in dictio:
        print('duplicate ' + line)
    else:
        dictio[parts[0]] = parts[1]
```

Where **parts[0]** is just a random part from the line to identify as unique, you can use any criteria you want as a key for the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some unix? What about `sort -u`, or if you need to uniquize only based on some column value, `sort -t',' -k1,1 -u`? And when your file grows, add something like `-S500MB` to keep the sorting in RAM ...